# Event listener from js static file pointing to incorrect path in Django

Tags: javascript, django, dom

This is the first time I am trying to integrate front-end with backend in Django. I currently have the following file structure:

```
my_project
 | 
 +-- my_app
 |  |  
 |  +-- ...
 |  +-- static
 |  |  |
 |  |  +--my_app
 |  |  |  +--app.js
 |  |  |  +--style.css
 |  |  |  +--back.png
 |  |  |  +--dice-1.png
 |  |  |  +--dice-2.png
 |  |  |  +--dice-3.png
 |  |  |  +--dice-4.png
 |  |  |  +--dice-5.png
 |  |  |  +--dice-6.png
 |  +-- templates
 |  |  |
 |  |  +--my_app
 |  |  |  +--index.html
 |  |  
 +-- manage.py
```

The problem is my css file from my_app/static is loading just fine - including the initial image file on the page, but when I try doing a click event on the app.js file to load an image from the static folder, i am getting an error on the console:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/js_dom/dice-1.png 404 (Not Found)
```

From my js file:

```
    // setter: change dice img
    var diceDOM = document.querySelector('.dice');  // select dice DOM
    diceDOM.src = `dice-${dice}.png`;  // use correct png based on roll <-- this is where I am getting the error
});
```

The initial image loads from my html file:

```
<img src="{% static 'js_dom/dice-5.png' %}" alt="Dice" class="dice">
```

And the path it loads from is:

```
http://localhost:8000/static/js_dom/dice-5.png
```

Which is very different from what I was getting from the console that threw the error.

I made sure to load all the static files from settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Here's the urls.py of the project:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('js_dom/', include('js_dom.urls'))
]
```

Here's the urls.py of the app:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.js_dom)
]
```

Is there a way to configure where the click points to? (/static/js_dom/ instead of /js_dom/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like you get that your problem is due to not referencing correctly the image path.

When you do this:

```
diceDOM.src = `dice-${dice}.png`;
```

You're actually adding `dice-1.png` as a relative path to your current URL. So, for example, if you had `127.0.0.1:8000/some/path`, then you're now going to have `127.0.0.1:8000/some/path/dice-1.png`.

There are two ways you can get the actual path to your image:

1. Hard-coding the path

```
diceDOM.src = `/static/js_dom/dice-${dice}.png`;
```

2. Saving the image path as a js variable when rendering the template.

So in your **HTML file** you would have (assuming that you are passing the dice number as a `dice` string variable in your context data):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var image_src = "{% static 'inventario/img/dice-'|add:number|add:'.png' %}";
</script>
```

Then, in your js file you can have:

```
diceDOM.src = image_src;
```